# Have I sinned if I removed pork from my meal, but continued to eat it, even though I had doubted the permissibility of doing so?

Tags: halal-haram, food, pork

I had recently ordered a steak sandwich, and as I was eating it, I found that it had another meat inside, which I suspect to be bacon. I spitted out what I had in my mouth, and washed my mouth. I had a feeling it was not permissible to finish the sandwich, but I did not want it to go to waste, so I removed the bacon, threw it away, and continued to eat it anyways. Later on, I had found out online that it was actually forbidden to eat tainted food, even if it had no pork, due to wetness. So, now I know, but I do not know if I had transgressed by not following my instincts.

Comment: Repent to Allah, ask his forgiveness and don't repeat

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the following hadith

On the authority of Abu 'Abdullah, Al-Nu'man Ibn Bashir (may Allah be pleased with them both) ,who said : *"I heard Allah's Messenger, sallallaahu alayhi wa sallam, say: "The Halal (lawful) is clear and the Haram (prohibited) is clear, and in between them there are some things that are doubtful ,which most people do not know - if they are Halal or Haram - Thus ,whoever avoids the doubtful, safeguards his religion and honor, but one who engages in the doubtful, falls in the Haram."*

If in your heart you feel you have committed a sin (from your question it sounds like you feel that you did) I think it is best to repent and seek forgiveness. Allah knows best.